# Can I install 2 Reliance control pro Tran 2 transfer switch 10 circuit on same panel?

Tags: generator, transfer-switch

I believe I have a sub panel because there is a breaker at the meter to shut off power. There is also a separate neutral bar from the ground bar in my breaker box.

Assuming I have that correct, onto my question.

In the sub panel, I have about 20 circuits. I was hoping in theory, if I wanted to, I could take 2 of the reliance pro Tran transfer switches (the 10 circuit models), mount two inlet boxes, and attach two separate generators to them. Half the homes circuits on one switch, half on another switch.

Is this possible? Not sure how much of my ignorance will show here, but when I see the transfer switch wiring diagrams, looks like  for a sub panel, you send the white wire to the neutral bar, the green wire to the ground bar, then the red wire to each circuit you want to power, and the black wire you wire nut to the black wire you removed from the breaker. So when I see this diagram, two transfer switches on all separate breakers, with two separate inlet boxes for two separate generators, seem completely independent of each other?

Comment: Why are you wanting to use two of the hokey select circuit transfer switches?  You can do this with *one* transfer panel for probably the same price or more cheaply, and get other benefits as well (switched neutral for full compatibility with a typical portable generator without having to fiddle with the generator's neutral strap, single hand movement operation for all circuits, full compatibility with GFCI and AFCI breakers, and so on)

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel no real particular reason. If anything it was just because I have two fairly good sized generators laying around. Seemed easy enough to understand. I’ll have to lookup what you sent. Sounds like it makes more sense anyway. Though, even that being said, does that make the above scenario at all possible?

Comment: I guess the bigger question is "what loads are you seeking to back up, and how big are your generators, really?"  Also, what make/model is your inside panel?

Comment: One is a 8k running watt and another is a 6.5k running watt. So between all those circuits it’ll really run the whole house. The small central AC, lights, fridge, etc. most of the cooking and heating appliances are natural gas.

Comment: I really haven’t done the math on any of it. I just looked up the largest model made by a company that had decent reviews, then quickly created a hypothetical scenario. In a sub panel with 20 individual breakers, could two transfer switches with independent power sources be utilized to energize all 20 circuits. Aside from that, nothing else was really done. Again, really hypothetical scenario.

Comment: Home line - homc30uc

Comment: How many square feet is the house, and how many amps does the A/C pull?  I'm wondering if it'd be possible to get basic lighting, HVAC, fridge, and any other minor loads that make sense (modem/router/phone interface, a couple of outlets for battery charging, radios/TVs, and such) onto one of the generators and simply have the other as a spare...also: I take it you're on city water/sewer since you didn't mention a well pump among your loads?

Comment: Correct. And without actually adding any of that up, I think you probably could with just the larger of the two gens. A modest 1800 sqft with the only really power draw being the condenser unit at around 24 amps. It’s the only large power drawer that would be running during an outage.

Comment: OK so the only reason you’re taking notice of those hokey, overpriced 10 circuit transfer switches just because they’re promoted/marketed a lot. That’s good, you don’t want em. Those panels only exist because they *used to* drop into any panel, even a Zinsco or Pushmatic.  But you can get a real panel that does the same thing much better for 1/3 the price. Nobody markets that because there’s no margin in it lol.

Comment: ThreePhaseEel I love watching you work, lol!

Comment: Can I ask what make/model your generators are btw @MZawg? Or do you want the ability to plug basically any small generator in?

Comment: Couple of duromax. I also appreciate all the advice. Again, rather a hypothetical question which still stands. While after doing some reading on your suggestions, there seems to be totally better ways to do this, And I’ll move forward with those better ways, and would be open to product suggestions as well. However, question does still remain and for my own edification I wouldn’t mind knowing. So given the post above, is there issue in doing it?

Comment: Also, as of now. I don’t really know what I want out of any of it. I simply looked at 20 individual circuit breakers, and then saw a reliance kit that covered 10. So that led me to say oh well if I had two of those switches and two separate generators and two separate inlet boxes, you could probably power all 20 circuits in the same panel. Whether that is the best way to do it or not wasn’t really the question. Though I again repeat, the advice was well worth giving and I hear you both loud and clear.